# Stop moving element when he outside of parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have an event listener keydown on arrow right, when you push the square moving on `xPX` but my parent element this `w` and `h` 
set a `100px` for example, and I would like to stop moving and I can't, I try with `element.offsetWidth > 0` so them you can move.

Please look this fiddle : [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/buq68pov/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few errors in your code. I've commented fixes. Here is how i made it for the right arrow - you can apply same logic to the rest of the moves...

Code:

```
    const carre = document.querySelector('.carre');
    const main = document.querySelector('.main');
    const w = main.offsetWidth - carre.offsetWidth; // this was wrong in your code

carre.style.left="0px"; // set start position 
    document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
        const positionLeft = parseInt(carre.style.left); //i've used style.left, rather, it gives expected numbers (10,20,30....)

        if(event.keyCode == '39') {
            if (positionLeft < w) { // this was fixed too
                carre.style.left = (positionLeft) + 10 + 'px';
            } else {
                carre.style.left = '0'
            }
        }

    })
```

DEmo:

```js
const carre = document.querySelector('.carre');
    const main = document.querySelector('.main');
    const w = main.offsetWidth - carre.offsetWidth; // this was wrong in your code

carre.style.left="0px"; // set start position 
    document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
        const positionLeft = parseInt(carre.style.left); //i've used style.left, rather, it gives expected numbers (10,20,30....)
     
        if(event.keyCode == '39') {
            if (positionLeft < w) { // this was fixed too
                carre.style.left = (positionLeft) + 10 + 'px';
            } else {
                carre.style.left = '0'
            }
        }
       
    })
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.carre {
           position:absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .main {
            position: relative;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
```

```html
<main class="main">
    <div class="carre"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

I rebuild your code:

```
 document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        const w = main.getBoundingClientRect().right - carre.getBoundingClientRect().right;
        const positionLeft = carre.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        if(event.keyCode == '39') {
            if (w >= 0) {
                carre.style.left = (positionLeft) + 10 + 'px';
            } else {
                carre.style.left = '0'
            }
        }
        if (event.keyCode == '37') {
            if (w >= 0) {
                carre.style.left = (positionLeft) - 10 + 'px';
            }else {
                carre.style.left = '0'
            }
        }
    })
```